# SAPUI5 Deployment: minimal set of files required to run

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I enjoy developing apps with SAPUI5 / OpenUI5. So far, I have extracted the complete SDK so debugging the controls is no problem. But the huge number of files sucks when deploying a new version.

I would therefore like to know what is the minimal set of files needed for SAPUI5 to run. I assume that the XXX-dbg.js files are not necessary, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, XXX-dbg.js files are not necessary, you can check whether you are running in debug mode by pressing on Shift+Alt+Ctrl+P in your app and uncheck "Use Debug Sources" (you can see the configuration also in the local-storage of your browser - check for sap-ui-debug key)

Comment: Are there any other files I do not need? What about the jqueryXXX files?

Comment: The jquery files are mandatory for SAPUI5, however if you are loading those files in your application you can use the option: src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core-nojQuery.js" https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f1dd0c6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html